# Cumulative LEDs

Tags: arduino, led, components, power-electronics, led-driver

For a better explanation let's think something like an equalizer bar
[image: Think one of these bars]
Think one of these bars. The coloumn has 16levels from bottom to top. If the level 10's led need to light up then, the all levels leds must be light up as well and etc for other conditions.

My aim is lighting up LEDs cumulatively with transistors or IC. To explain it, for example: I have an decoder and 3 leds.

- Output1(of the decoder) pin will light up LED1
- Output2(of the decoder) pin will light up LED1 and LED2
- Output3(of the decoder) pin will light up all 3 of the LEDs

How can i achieve that system in minimal way. By the way leds are standard 5mm. They drain 20mA.

Edit: Sorry i forgot. Arduino connected to input of the decoder so i want to control 3leds with 2pins of the arduino.
Leds are operated on 5V and the decoder is 74HC139.

Comment: You have the [tag:arduino] tag, but you don't mention any arduino. If there is no arduino here, remove the tag. If there is an arduino, explain where it is!

Comment: Sorry i forgot. Arduino connected to input of the decoder so i want to control 3leds with 2pins of the arduino and it must be in cumulative way.

Comment: What decoder IC is being used? What is the LED supply voltage? The LED's will draw 20mA only if the resistor in series with them is a low value.

Comment: Leds are operated on 5V and the decoder is 74HC139.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the details which clarified in the comments. You should aim to make it easy for people to give a good answer to your question.

Comment: You have three LEDs. You have an Arduino with > 3 GPIO pins. You want to _sequentially_ light the LEDs. What's the problem? Connecting an LED to a GPIO pin is one of the first tutorials on the Arduino.

Comment: Not sequential. Like a light bar or like an equalizer . But there will be 10-15 channel(light bar). Then 30-45pins are required.

Comment: The more things are "explained' the worse it gets.  Assuming that @Reactionic understands the question, it isn't being very well communicated here.

Comment: its not exactly what you want but google "ShiftPWM"

Comment: You need summing diodes and a resistor to match the current for each LED. The diodes (1N5817) will cause a .5 volt drop, so you have to account for that as well. Most LED's need about 3.0 volts to turn on. You will need 'n' diodes for each state. You need at least 3.5 volts to turn on any led. State 3 where all 3 LED's are on will consume a lot of current for even a 74HCxx series to drive. The LED's cannot be in series as you would need 10 volts or more to turn ON all 3 LED's. Reconsider your design.

Comment: Consider using an LM3914 or LM3915. They are built to be LED drivers, including 'bar ' mode. No resistors or diodes per LED.

Comment: I will check "ShiftPWM" and LM series IC

Comment: There are many ways of doing this, but a 74HC139 is not a logical part of any of them, as it does not have cumulative behavior.  You could easily make something that did using a simple programmable logic device or an old PROM, but serial schemes are more readily available and will support far more LEDs from your two pins.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if you wanted to keep it digital and wanted to run a serial interface to reduce the number of pins, you could use a max7219.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question:

> How can I use a few gpio pins to drive a led bar graph?

You need an LM3914 or LM3916.

Comment: You build an R2R ladder from the 2 pins to get a drive signal for the IC's. Or an R+R ladder.

Comment: But how can i connect Arduino to LM IC. Analog write function uses PWM. Do i need something between arduino and LM IC?

Comment: It is silly to convert digital to analog just to feed it into a LM391x chip.  And it is NOT AT ALL CLEAR why we have a perfectly good microcontroller here (Arduino) but @Reactionic can use only 2 pins???  If you really want to use 2 pins (I2C) then use a MAX7219 chip which will control 64 LEDs from 2 wires.  Or the new Charlie-plex boards from Adafruit, etc.

Comment: Yes it is, but that's what he is asking for, no? Lol. I think we both suggested the max 7219 at the same time 

Comment: @Reactionic There are tons of examples, but as RichardCrowley points out, there are much better ways of doing than what your asking.